# fpdf line break not working

Tags: php, knockout.js, fpdf

I have a knockout observable which contains a text that has line breaks in it.

Like this:

```
 var  str += item.first_name +  " " + item.last_name + "," + item.occupation + "\n\n"; 
 str += "RE :" + item.first_name +  " " + item.last_name + ", DOB: "
                            + item.date_of_birth + "\n"; 
text = ko.observable(str);
```

The method that I am using to display the string is:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,8,$text);
```

The result that I get in my pdf is :

```
 Dr. Bart grahamson,MBBSRE :Jack Junior, DOB: 1985-01-02
```

What is a way to catch those line breaks?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `$text` ?

Comment: how are you getting from your js variable -> `text = ko.observable(str);` to your php variable -> `$text`? It could be that the js is already parsing the line break `\n`, so it is no longer in that format to be used in the fpdf method. If the line breaks are always in the same spot, you could reinsert them -> `$pdf->MultiCell(0,8,preg_replace("(RE :)","\n\n"."\${1}",$test)."\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Use \n and \r.

```
var  str += item.first_name +  " " + item.last_name + "," + item.occupation + "\n \r\r \n"; 
 str += "RE :" + item.first_name +  " " + item.last_name + ", DOB: "
                            + item.date_of_birth + "\n \r"; 
text = ko.observable(str);
```