# Echo line break from variable in textarea (and fpdf)

Tags: php, html, fpdf

In my database I've

```
Linetext1 \r\nLinetext2
```

I then fech data:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $mydata_array = $row['myrow'];
}
```

then the echo part:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <5; ++$I){
     echo $mydata_array[$i];
}
```

But it literally output in textarea (and in fpdf) Linetext1 \r\nLinetext2. I did try a string replace as suggested in other questions

```
echo (str_replace('\r\n', '<br />', $mydata_array[$i]);
```

but then I literally have

```
Linetext1 <br />Linetext2
```

Thanks for your help!

**SOLUTION**

After Sergey's answer, I used this:

```
echo (str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array("", "\n"), $mydata_array[$i]);
```

PS It's important to use MultiCell and not single Cell

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218997/fpdf-line-break-not-working

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks, how could I use the answer of that post in my case? I already have \r\n, but it doesn't work...

Comment: The post mentions using `\n \r` instead.

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks, but the problem was not in the \n \r. They already were in my variable. The problem was that they were not interpreted in the right way. Pls see Sergey's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<br />` tags are useless in a textarea, unless it's a rich text editor area (and therefore not exactly a textarea) - it needs `\n` or `\r\n` line breaks. FPDF needs `\n` breaks, too. What you should probably do is to replace the `\r` and `\n` literals to actual line breaks:

```
echo (str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array("", "\n"), $mydata_array[$i]);
```

**Edit:** As per your testing, `\r` should be wiped out completely, because it only confuses the FPDF without adding any real value.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. On what I understand from your answer is that by replacing '\r' with "\r" I'm telling the software to replace the string \r with the command \r. I didn't know (single vs double) quotes could be used in such fashion. Thanks for teaching me that!

Comment: "\r" is not a command but an actual carriage return ASCII symbol. It has to be in double quotes though, because otherwise (in single quotes) PHP will treat it as two separate characters, a slash and a small R. More information on this available [here](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Sorry Sergey, but on fpdf (I actually use the tFPDF) it outputs two little squares... do you have any ideas??

Comment: See my modified answer. My guess is that FPDF wants only "\n" and not "\r\n".

Comment: Thanks Sergey. After your edit, I used this way, if not fpdf was adding 2 lines `echo (str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array("", "\n"), $mydata_array[$i]);` (see my edited question) Thanks again!!